# Remote Desktop connect

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

My work computer is running on Windows 7 Ultimate, and my home laptop is running on Windows 7 Home Premium.

I want to connect my work computer from my home laptop, but whenever I try to do it gives me an error message saying:

```
Remote desktop can't connect to the computer for one of the following reasons

    1.Remote access to the server is not enabled.
    2.The remote computer is turn off.
    3.The remote computer is not available in the network.
```

But when I tried to connect from my colleague's desktop I can connect to my computer.

Please help me. I need to connect to my work computer from home.

Comment: @MMH is your work computer reachable at all from your home computer (over VPN or directly)?

Comment: Serge I am not very sure. I have never used VPN and don't even know how to use.

Comment: @MMH so what do you do to connect?

Comment: I want to use windows 'remote computer connect' to access my work computer.

Comment: I got this. but what exactly do you tell to the utility where to connect to?

Comment: I gave the IP address of my work computer and also I tried with the name of my work computer...

Comment: ok. is the IP of your computer belongs to publicly accessible addresses? if you do not know what ip addresses are public just post here the beginning of address (first and second group of digits will be enough)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16939/discussion-between-serge-and-mmh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give TeamViewer (free, although there are commercial versions available) a try. TeamViewer is similar to RDP or VNC (you see the desktop of the target computer), and it communicates over 80 and 443 so you will not need open any additional ports on a firewall in order to get it to work.

If you sign up for an account (free) you can even have a list of computers to connect to right there in the application window.

http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx

Here is a quick tutorial explaining how TeamViewer works and how to configure it

http://www.wikihow.com/Use-TeamViewer

Comment: Thanks for the comment... this asked this question last year.. and from last yr I am using teamviewer..thanks anyways.

Comment: Would you mind marking this as the answer so if other people have the same issue they can easily tell that this solution worked for you without having to read the comments?

Answer (score 0):

Unless every device on your companies network has a public IP address, I think you have been trying to connect via the private IP which only is contactable from within the network.

Go to www.whatismyip.com from your work machine and make a note of the external publically reachable ip of your network.

You (or the network administrator) needs to open a NAT rule for port 3389 TCP which is the port used for remote desktop and forward it to the private ip of your computer.

Then, next time you connect to the public ip of your work network, all remote desktop traffic will forward to your work machine and it should work fine!